# Include XHTML page into another via jQuery post and then perform actions on the loaded page while still being on the main page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, redirect, xhtml

I have a XHTML web page that needs to load another one (different url) in a div (its ID will be pageContentDIV).

```
<div id="pageContentDIV">
</div>
```

I have achieved this by using the post method of jQuery.

The code that I have is the following:

```
var pageContentDIV = $('#pageContentDIV');
[...]

$.post(externalPageURL, {username: "abc", password: "def"}, function(data){
   pageContentDIV.html(data);
});
```

This works, however it has one weird quirk that I am struggling to fix.
(I've also tried having ui:include and ui:insert tags but that didn't work either).

The page that I am trying to load has a form in it plus a table (initially empty). When the submit button is pressed, an ajax request is issued to retrieve information from a database and then populate the table with that information.
What I would like to have is the following scenario:

1. user goes to page1
2. page1 loads page2 into a DIV of page1 (form + table)
3. user clicks submit button on the form loaded in step 2
4. table grid is populated and the user is still on page1

What I currently have is the following scenario:

1. user goes to page1
2. page1 loads page2 into a DIV of page1
3. user clicks submit button on the form loaded in step 2
4. user is redirected towards page2 (URL changes to page2) and table grid is populated

The difference between the two behaviors is that I would like to keep my user on page1, however it seems like I am missing something.

Would it be possible to have the desired behavior without changing the code of page2?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hm, do you have a nested form there?

Comment: @Mr Lister -> I only have <h:form> elements in page2 and they are not nested. Other suggestions?